# Oracle How to assign usernames

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I assign usernames for students using their initials followed by numbers that increment?   I'm not sure how many students I have in my database and I would like their usernames to look like so "AC001, JD003 for example. And also, If the have similar initials I would like the username to continue incrementing in that order. For example "AC001" and "AC002"

Comment: try this select CONCAT('USER',YOURSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL) FROM DUAL;

Comment: Is the number incremented independently from the two letters (1,000 students)? Or do you mean each of the 26 x 26 = 676 letter combinations will have its own dependent number sequence (676 x 1,000 = 676,000 students)?

Comment: It's better to have arbitrary rolling numbers and letters as your usernames because the problem with letter combinations made from names is some combinations would be a lot more common than others. You'll be very hard-pressed to find the combination XX or XY incrementing more than 1 whereas you can easily run out of combinations starting with S. This is why government ID numbers do not consist of name-initial combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a trigger on `BEFORE INSERT` event and a sequence to implement this.

I will assume your table is as follows:

```
TABLE user
( userid     VARCHAR2(100) -- PRIMARY KEY COLUMN
, firstname VARCHAR2(100)
, lastname    VARCHAR2(100)
, .... -- Other columns
);
```

Create a sequence as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sq_userid;
```

You insert rows with `userid` column set to null.

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (null, 'Jack', 'Daniels', ....);
```

Then, your trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_user
BEFORE INSERT ON user
REFERENCING new AS new old AS old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.userid IS NULL THEN
        :new.userid := UPPER(LEFT(firstname, 1))
                      || UPPER(LEFT(lastname, 1))
                      || TO_CHAR(sq_userid.nextval, '099');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The trigger will put 'JD001' AS the value for `userid` in this instance.

For more information- [Coding triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm), [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) and [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm).

Comment: I was thinking I should create a cursor, them create an SQL statement in search for the s_first, s_last. This is what I have so far, very very little, sorry for that  
  
DECLARE    
CURSOR un_cur IS    
SELECT s_last, s_first INTO    
FROM tst_student    
ORDER BY s_last, s_first;     
BEGIN

Comment: @Rachcha He probably wants each letter combination to have its own sequence. With your answer, what would happen after the 1000th student?

Comment: @ADTC- I wrote this for only three digits because the question mentions only three digits. If there have to be more digits then just change the `'099'` string to `'0999'` for four digits, `'09999'` for five digits and so on.

Comment: @user3056094- What is your exact business requirement? From your question I understand that you want to store a unique identifier for each user based on the initials and a unique number. From your comments I think you just want this identifier to display in a SELECT statement. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and describe what you have tried and what you want your code to do?

Comment: what exactly is new  as new ? and old as old? are you referencing table names to what? Im not sure I understand this part. @Rachcha

Comment: As we have to generate a `userid` for each user, I have written a row level trigger. `FOR EACH ROW` clause defines row level trigger. In this, we can access the new values being inserted using the `:new` keyword, provided we define `REFERENCING new AS new`. You can omit the `old AS old` part for an insert trigger.

Comment: Edited my answer and added links for your reference at the bottom.

Comment: I created the sequence 
--CREATE SEQUENCE uname_seq;


I altered my tst_student table 
--ALTER TABLE tst_student
--ADD U_NAME VARCHAR2(15);


and now I need to create the trigger, which I have done, but it gives me a warning stating "EXECUTION COMPLETED WITH WARNING" @Rachcha

Comment: Query the table `user_errors` with the name of your trigger to retrieve the warning messages. As long as there are no compilation errors, your code is fine.

Comment: @Rachcha that was not what I meant. He clarifies in the question that he wants each letter combination to have its own running sequence >> AA001, AA002, ...; AB001, AB002, ...; AC001, AC002, ...; ... Given all combinations, this can potentially give 676,000 unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will also work
    1st Create sequence user_seq;

```
insert into user values('user_name'||user_seq.nextval);
```

you can modify above query as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a solution, but it's in MySQL. I'm sure you can get the general idea and convert it into Oracle (there's an Oracle 11g option in SQL Fiddle itself): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ed5/1

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE ALPHA_ROLL (
  ALPHA1 CHAR(1),
  ALPHA2 CHAR(1),
  ROLL INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(ALPHA1, ALPHA2)
  )//

CREATE TABLE user (
  USERID VARCHAR(5),
  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100),
  LASTNAME VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (USERID)
  )//

CREATE TRIGGER trg_user
BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @gen_user_id = 
    (SELECT CONCAT(ALPHA1,ALPHA2,LPAD((ROLL+1), 3, '0'))
    FROM ALPHA_ROLL
    WHERE ALPHA1 = UPPER(LEFT(NEW.firstname, 1))
    AND ALPHA2 = UPPER(LEFT(NEW.lastname, 1))
    LIMIT 1);

  IF (@gen_user_id IS NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO ALPHA_ROLL (ALPHA1, ALPHA2, ROLL)
    VALUES (UPPER(LEFT(new.firstname, 1)), UPPER(LEFT(new.lastname, 1)), 1);
    SET @GEN_USER_ID =
      CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(new.firstname, 1)),
             UPPER(LEFT(new.lastname, 1)),
             '001');
  ELSE
    UPDATE ALPHA_ROLL SET ROLL = ROLL + 1
    WHERE ALPHA1 = UPPER(LEFT(new.firstname, 1))
    AND ALPHA2 = UPPER(LEFT(new.lastname, 1));
  END IF;

  SET new.userid = @GEN_USER_ID;
END//
```

**SQL:**

```
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Johnnie', 'Walker');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Jason', 'Mraz');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Mariah', 'Carrie');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Justin', 'Morg');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Matthew', 'Congoman');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Jack', 'Waltson');
INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('Jojo', 'Wonderful');

SELECT * FROM USER;
SELECT * FROM ALPHA_ROLL;
```

**Result:**

```
USERID  FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
JM001   Jason     Mraz
JM002   Justin    Morg
JW001   Johnnie   Walker
JW002   Jack      Waltson
JW003   Jojo      Wonderful
MC001   Mariah    Carrie
MC002   Matthew   Congoman

ALPHA1  ALPHA2  ROLL
J       M       2
J       W       3
M       C       2
```